# How can I adjust the images in my webpage like so?

Tags: html, css

My web page looks like this:

[image]

As you see, there are two images: a border (image to the right) and a photograph (to the left). I want to position the photographic images so that it's inside the image border. Before you say can't you create a border, nope - needs to be linked to a specific image on the web. So I've tried just adjusting the settings right:20px; ect but nothing seems to allow it.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you share the code you try on a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Possibly useful link: [CSS border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?
I used divs, but you can change them for img tags, or you can use them to wrap the elements (links, images, iframe, as I don't know how are you including the external files).

HTML:

```
<div class="class1">Teri</div>
<div class="class2">Mare</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class1{
background:#ccc;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
left:10px;
z-index:9999; /* change the stack order */
}
.class2{
background:#666;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
left:10px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tSPn6/

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is add the `<div>` tag and `</div>` to end the tag
next you need to put this into your `css` `<style>` tag and write it like this

```
div
{
border-style:url('image');
}
```

or

```
div
{
border-style: the style here;
}
```

i hope that helps you out